# multiprocessing Pool hangs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gitpython

I've create a Pool to do git clone using Gitpython. There is a large git repo and needs more time than others to clone. Each process do a clone work for one repo. The `Pool` I used as follows:

```py
multi_res = [p.apply_async(runfunc, args=(incl_info, project_root, skip_dirs,)) 
                for incl_info in incl_infos]
LogInfo('Waiting for all subprocesses done...')
for i in range(len(incl_infos)):
    while not multi_res[i].ready():
        LogInfo("Downloading now")
        time.sleep(5)
p.close()
p.join()
```

It works perfectly in most case. But will often hangs in the largest repo. It's wired that when i just clone the repo individually, It works fine. So i wonder if there is some block in python `multiprocessing.Pool`.

I've strace the hanged git clone process . The git process output as follows:

```
Process 27649 attached
read(6, 0x7ffc36dae050, 4)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=2895997, ptr=0x2c307d}} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
read(6, 0x7ffc36dae050, 4)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=2895997, ptr=0x2c307d}} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
read(6, 0x7ffc36dae050, 4)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=2895997, ptr=0x2c307d}} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
read(6, 0x7ffc36dae050, 4)              = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=2895997, ptr=0x2c307d}} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 0
```

The git-lfs output as follows:

```
Process 28006 attached
[ Process PID=28006 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
futex(0x88b982c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL
```

Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've find the reason. It is because i used a `gitpython` lib and it hangs sometime.